# Using position:absolute changes elements placed in next columns in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please refer to code. While coding in bootstrap, I have deliberately placed one element at col-xs-4 having col-xs-offset-8 and another element at col-xs-2 in a single row; which means that the element having col-xs-2 is pushed to the next row. This works just fine. But, after I use absolute positioning for the col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-8 element, the subsequent element is also displaced. How can I avoid the next element from being displaced?

Also, to have responsive design, I don't want to use height and width properties on the cubespinner class and instead use the full horizontal space and the height of the image to be used by the col-xs-4 container. Like, currently, the animation works fine in full screen but not in resized windows. How best to achieve this?

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
  }

  body {

    background-color: #111;
  }

  .navibar {
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }


  .cubespinner {
    -webkit-animation: spincube 10s alternate infinite;
    animation: spincube 10s alternate infinite;

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -webkit-transform-origin: 53px 53px 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 53px 53px 0;
    -ms-transform-origin: 53px 53px 0;
    transform-origin: 53px 53px 0;
  }

  .cubespinner div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 440px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    font-family: 'Baloo Paaji', cursive;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ddd;
    text-decoration: underline;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    background: rgba(75, 105, 105, 0.8);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.5);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  }

  .cubespinner a:link {
    color: #ddd;
    text-decoration-color: #ddd;
  }

  .cubespinner a:visited,
  .cubespinner a:hover,
  .cubespinner a:active {
    color: #5bc0de;
    text-decoration-color: #5bc0de;
  }



  .face1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(50px);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(50px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(50px);
    transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(50px);
  }

  .face2 {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(50px);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(50px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(50px);
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(50px);
  }

  .face3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(50px);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(50px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(50px);
    transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(50px);
  }

  .face4 {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(270deg) translateZ(50px);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(270deg) translateZ(50px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(270deg) translateZ(50px);
    transform: rotateX(270deg) translateZ(50px);
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes spincube {
    0%,
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    }
    25% {
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    }
    50% {
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    }
    75% {
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(-270deg);
    }
  }

  @keyframes spincube {
    0%,
    100% {
      -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
      transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    }
    25% {
      -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
      transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    }
    50% {
      -moz-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
      transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    }
    75% {
      -moz-transform: rotateX(-270deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateX(-270deg);
      transform: rotateX(-270deg);
    }
  }
  </style>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-8">
        <div class="cubespinner">
          <div class="face1">
            <a href="#" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/nitt.png" alt="logo"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="face2">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">
              <h2 class="text">Text for Test Purposes</h2>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="face3">
            <a href="#" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/nitt.png" alt="logo"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="face4">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">
              <h2 class="text">Text for Test Purposes</h2>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked navibar">
          <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp Test1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp Test2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp Test3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp Test4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp Test5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

EDIT: Added an image of the look I'm trying to achieve. I want this look long long with the present animation. [image: I want the elements to be positioned this way]

Comment: Why are you using absolute positioning?  It's not clear from the question what your intended layout is.

Comment: yes please  it not clear please  i thinks  better way image screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add position:absolute on an object you take it completely out of the normal DOM flow. As a result, anything you place after it will adjust as though the absolutely positioned element does not exist and simply reflow to fill the gap.

To resolve this, YOU SHOULD NEVER put abs pos on the grid elements.

Absolute should be applied to the contents of the grid, not the grid itself. This will prevent your issue from happening.

So, just put whatever you need to remain in position inside of your grid, and then apply the positioning to those elements. The rest of the page will flow as it should.

Alternately, if you set position:relative of the parent, and position:absolute on the child, you can move the child relative to the parent without impacting the rest of your DOM.